# App crashes when running on iPhone 5s but works when running on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt

I have a code that fetches information from a website and shows it on a table view.
This is my code

```
  if ([event.eventDescription containsString:@"src="]) {

  NSError *error = nil;
  NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

  [detector enumerateMatchesInString:event.eventDescription
  options:0
  range:NSMakeRange(0, event.eventDescription.length)
  usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
  {
    if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
    {
      NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result.URL];
      NSLog(@"Image Url = %@",str);
      event.stringImageURL = str;
    }
  }];

 }
```

When i run this code on the iPhone stimulator it works perfectly fine. However when run it on my iPhone it crashes. It shows a SIGABRT error at this `event.stringImageURL = str;` line of code. Can somebody help me.

Edit :
This is shown on my log.

```
-[Events setStringImageURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17002bd40
2015-03-20 09:22:54.047 PforSST1[346:22070] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Events setStringImageURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17002bd40'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1860ee530 0x1970780e4 0x1860f55f4 0x1860f23ac 0x185ff6c4c 0x100093498 0x187069f34 0x100093114 0x10011cfd4 0x10011cf94 0x100121c28 0x1860a62ec 0x1860a4394 0x185fd11f4 0x18f3fb6fc 0x18a96210c 0x100094a70 0x1976f6a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my events.h

```
@interface Events : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *eventName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *eventDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringImageURL;

@end
```

This is my events.m

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Events *)otherObject
{
    return [self.eventName compare:otherObject.eventName];
}
```

Comment: I would say that the issue is your *event.stringImageURL* is not of type string and assigning the string to it is causing the crash.

Comment: Please remove all the irrelevant code in your question and make it easier to see the part causing the issue.

Comment: Please show the `Events` class and remove unnecessary code from your post so we don't have to read a wall of code.

Comment: my event.stringImageURL is a `NSString`

Comment: Make a check list of following : Have u synthesised property, Allocated memory? At last use NSMutableString instead. This should work.